# "Authentication required" SmtpException trying to send mail from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I'm running the C# code listed at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-net.html, trying to send a test email from an EC2 instance.  I can easily run the equivalent code using the gmail SMTP server, but when I use SES as my SMTP server I an SmtpException with the error message:

```
 The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required
```

In SES, I've done the following:

1. Gone through the "Verify a new Email Address" process for both my "From" address and my "To" address.  (My SES account still has "sandbox" access according to the Sending Statistics page.)
2. Verified my companyname.com under SES Domains
3. Enabled DKIM settings under SES Domains
4. Created the following Sending authorization policy under SES Domains:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "stmt123456789",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/ses-smtp-user.20190805-123456"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:1234567890:identity/mycompany.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

My suspicion is that the problem is in my identity policy or how I've linked it back to my EC2 instance, but I don't know.

Comment: I've been getting this periodically with the email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com endpoint. It's been failing on maybe 10% of emails - maybe more. The odd thing is all emails are being sent to our own support@ address so it shouldn't be anything related to an invalid destination. I tried creating new credentials since these were active for years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you using in section:

```
String SMTP_USERNAME = "smtp_username";
String SMTP_PASSWORD = "smtp_password";
```

The Sending authorization policy looks correct and more ever it is not required if your ses-smtp-user and SES verified domain in the same account, you need to make sure that you're using the credentials you created from SES console --> SMTP settings --> Credentials.

Since you're using SMTP, SMTP credentials are required, it won't work if you're using normal IAM access key and secret key. The SMTP access and secret keys should be created from SES console.

Comment: I _thought_ I was using the credentials from the SES console...  I'll re-confirm these tonight.

Comment: Ouch.  I'd been using "ses-smtp-user.20190805-123456" as my user name, instead of the actual username.  Thanks James for your quick response, and for your clarification of the authorization policy.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note when using AWS SES that if you create your own IAM user you cannot use the naked `Access Key` and `secret`.

You must **derive the user's SMTP credentials** from their AWS credentials using an algorithm

See [AWS SES docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html)

Symptoms of using the naked IAM credentials is an error like

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required

With that knowledge, you can find various [tools in your preferred language](https://gist.github.com/damusix/c12400ee0ccb7e56351619ae2b19a303) to do the conversion.

Comment: I get this same message when using the proper SMTP credentials. But not all emails. Trying to recreate new ones since the ones I'm using are years old. It's very odd.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SES SMTP interface to send email in more than one Region, you must generate a set of SMTP credentials for each Region that you plan to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).